# Methanol Evaporation/Degradation From Surfaces

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've seen resources indicate how quickly methanol in small amounts evaporates from a dry surface in open air. Does this apply to methanol mixed with other substances, such as that in wiper fluid? I'm curious if some residual methanol would just remain on a surface with a small amount of fluid residue (such as a countertop, car interior, etc.) indefinitely until washed off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good point! Since methanol and water are miscible:

- The remaining liquid water would tend to "hold onto" methanol.
- As the water molecules evaporate, that removes heat energy and slows evaporation of methanol.

It *would* take the methanol longer to evaporate *in toto*. However, even so, water evaporates readily, too, so there's no need to wash off the remaining mixture, at least under normal use outdoors. If you were to spill a 4 liter bottle of windshield (*AKA windscreen in the UK*) wiper fluid in a garage, that *would* be a more serious problem. An ordinary wet/dry shop vac could cause fire or explosion, so repeated wet mopping and wringing of the mop would take a while.

Comment: Fortunately nothing like that! Just got splashed with some wiper fluid while standing next to a car a couple of weeks ago and touched a few surfaces in the process of getting cleaned up that I wasn't sure were adequately cleaned after, some of which were in the car itself. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: This is not a site for health info, but, *generally speaking*, though methanol *is* absorbed through skin, absorption is not rapid, so I'd not worry about a bit splashed on open skin and rinsed. If it saturated clothing, holding it in contact with skin, or if I had to deal with large amounts on a regular basis, there would be reason to take action. *Trivia: ethanol was used to reduce toxicity of methanol: https://mdpoison.com/media/SOP/mdpoisoncom/ToxTidbits/2013/June%202013%20ToxTidbits.pdf*

Comment: Makes sense! I talked to poison control immediately after for the medical advice, was just curious about persistence on surfaces.